# Dictionary key value pairs

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key-value

thanks in advance for any help, it's much appreciated.

I have created the following program:

```
from random import *

def show_flashcard():
    """ Show the user a random key and ask them
        to define it. Show the definition
        when the user presses return.    
    """
    random_key = choice(list(glossary))
    print('Define: ', random_key)
    input('Press return to see the definition')
    print(glossary[random_key])

# Set up the glossary

glossary = {'word1':'definition1',
            'word2':'definition2',
            'word3':'definition3'}

# The interactive loop

exit = False
while not exit:
    user_input = input('Enter s to show a flashcard and q to quit: ')
    if user_input == 'q':
        exit = True
    elif user_input == 's':
        show_flashcard()
    else:
        print('You need to enter either q or s.')
```

Current Output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XZTH.png)

I want to modify the showflashcard() function so that it picks an entry at random from all of the dictionary entries, then choose at random whether to show a user the entry itself or the associated definition. When the user presses return the user should be shown either the corresponding definition, if the entry was displayed first, or the corresponding entry, if the definition was displayed first.

I believe I need to set up another variable i.e. random_def but I am struggling to get further than that. I don't understand how to take the random_key my program has chosen and then use that to display either that random_key or the definition from the key value pair.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

look like you want to chose a random key from your map

```
import random
dict_keys = glossary.keys()
random.shuffle(dict_keys)
### now just select the first key of the shuffled list and get the definition from your dictionary  ###
definition = glossary[dict_keys[0]]
```

Comment: Hi, thank for you reply but I don't think it covers what I am trying to do.  I only want to modify the existing show_flashcard() function.

e.g. 

I want to choose a random key i.e.  'word1' then once I have that stored as a variable 'random_key', then randomly choose whether to print that or print it's associated value i.e. 'definition 1'

Once the user has been shown the output, they hit return and get the associated key or value i.e. definition1 or word1'

Comment: well you can use `round(random.random())` this will give either 0 or 1 randomly make a simple if statement like this `if round(random.random()) == 1` show word `else` show definition